# Why doesn't anything happen to the iterated value when I increase the variable inside the for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

If I have this code:

```
total_pages= 5
for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
    page +=1
    print(page)
```

It'll print this:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

It's interesting and I'm curious, because an intern asked me why it's not printed every 2.
I would like to understand why the **page** takes on a new value in the range regardless of whether I increased its value within the **for**
I know WHAT is happening here, but I'd like to understand HOW.

Comment: You are assigning a new value to `page` on each iteration and print that value +1. That's it.